# Are you able to compute the bending moment exerted on the inner edges of parallelepiped box under inner pressure?

Tags: pressure, moments, pressure-vessel, bending

Suppose you have a parallelepiped box of dimensions $a\times b\times L$ with $L\gg (a+b)$, filled with simple distilled water exerting a uniform and constant inner pressure $p$ as reported in figure.

It is easy to compute the value of bending moments per unit length for the lines $N = \overline{AB} = b$ and $M = \overline{AD} = a$ as the sum of the bending moment at the centre line and the bending moment at the corner as follows:

$M_M=p\frac{a^2}{8}+M_A$,

$M_N=p\frac{b^2}{8}+M_A$

But, I would like to know if someone is able to show, with a step by step demonstration, that the bending moment occurring on the four inner corners $A, B, C$ and $D$ is the same on each corner and it has the following expression:

$M_i=-p\frac{\left( a^3+b^3 \right)}{12(a+b)}$

Where $i = 1,...,4$ is the index for the four edges $A,B,C,D$.The measurement unit of $M_i$ is the one of a bending moment per unit length $N mm/mm$.

It is enough if you know a book dealing with this demonstration.

[image: parallelepiped container under inner pressure]

Comment: What is the unit of the equation for Mi? Where does the moment occur - on lines AB, BC, CD, DC, or the corners A, B, C & D? Also, type of fluid pressure - linear varying over the height?

Comment: Hi, the measurement unit of Mi is the one of a bending moment per unit length (N*mm/mm). The formula reported refers to the moment occurring on each edge (corner) A, B, C and D and it is the same on each corner. I would like to know if there is a demonstration or a book that demonstrates it. Inner pressure is constant and uniform on each side.

Comment: Looks like the equations for M_M, M_N represent the fixed end moment in the middle of the edges of the strips along the lengths of a & b respectively with a mistake, on M_A, which does not equal, unless a = b. It may help if you can provide the reference, that lists these equations.